# What is the polarizability of a classical hydrogen atom with a perpendicularly applied E-field?

Tags: electromagnetism, polarization

Consider a classical hydrogen atom with a planar orbit and an electric field applied perpendicularly to the plane of orbit. Is there a polarizability of the hydrogen atom, and if so what is it?

My guess is that there is not, because there is no component of the E-field which overlaps with the plane of orbit, but I'm hesitant because this question was posed to me in a place where I would not expect a trick question. (The original question asks to simply find the polarizability)

Comment: The potential that the wavefunction sees is distorted by the electric field, regardless of the orientation of the electric field itself. This means that both the eigen-energies and the eigenstates are also distorted. I would expect a polarization to develop along the direction of the electric field, as the electron wavefunction shifts in the opposite direction of the applied electric field. (I would also expect a splitting of the $p$-orbital energies, with the $p$-orbital oriented along the axis of the electric field having a different energy than the $p$-orbitals perpendicular to it).

Comment: Why would the electric field need to have a component in the plane of the orbit?

Comment: @probably_someone The OP specified “classical hydrogen atom”, so no wavefunctions.

Comment: I think the plane of the orbit just shifts a bit, in the opposite direction of the field, remaining parallel to what it was but no longer centered on the proton. Draw a force diagram with two forces on the electron causing a centripetal acceleration toward the center of the circular orbit (not the proton).

Comment: @G.Smith Oops. Didn't see that for some reason.

Comment: There is no such thing as a classical hydrogen atom. Do you mean highly excited states? Note that in the hydrogen ground state the angular momentum is zero, unlike for the orbital you are describing.

Comment: @G.Smith that makes sense. Thanks.